# Converting SQL query to linq query expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SQL query that I am trying to convert into a LINQ query expression in C#, but I can not do it properly.

The query is as follows:

```
select 
    P.id, P.name, COUNT(S.orderqty)
from 
    product as P 
inner join 
    sales as S on P.id = S.id
group by 
    p.id, p.name
```

My linq code:

```
IQueryable<ReportType1> query = 
    from product in EngineContext.Products
    join SalesOrder inEngineContext.SalesOrderDetails  
    on product.ProductID equals SalesOrder.ProductID
    group SalesOrder.OrderQty by product into groups
    select new ReportType1() {    
        Year = null,
        ProducId = groups.Key.ProductID,
        Name = groups.Key.Name,
        Quantity = ??
    };
```

What to write for value of `Quantity`?

Answer (score 1):

Count method of group:

```
select new ReportType1
{
    Year = null,
    ProducId = groups.Key.ProductID,
    Name = groups.Key.Name,
    Quantity = groups.Count()
}
```

Comment: @MohammadRezaTaghipour what do you mean? It works because it's LinqToSql and it translate methods to sql-code

Comment: yes,my question is not clear! i mean what does "groups.Count()" refer to? does it refer to exactly "SalesOrder.OrderQty"?

Comment: @MohammadRezaTaghipour it refers to your groupping by `product`, so it counts in every group

Comment: @MohammadRezaTaghipour Please consider checking the answer as the right answer if it was helpful to encourage more pepole to answer your questions

Comment: @MohammadRezaTaghipour can you accept my answer or should I improve it?